# Using a variable as the subject of autocmd FileType

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Is it possible to use a variable as the subject of an `autocmd`?

I want to allow plugin users to define a list of `FileTypes` the plugin will operate on.

This requires that I set an `autocommand` for each of the given `FileTypes`.

The below code doesn't work:

```
let g:enabledFileTypes = ['javascript', 'vim']

autocmd FileType g:enabledFileTypes * call myFunction()
```

This does:

```
autocmd FileType javascript,vim * call myFunction()
```

Is it possible to declare an autocommand that uses a variable as the file type list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `*` glob is useless in a `FileType` autocommand.

You can `join()` that list into a comma-separated string:

```
execute "autocmd FileType " . join(g:enabledFileTypes, ",") . " call myFunction()"
```